# How to delete a record in MVC without using a View?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Normally I put the following in my Index view:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.UserId }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');", @class = "delete-button" })
```

This allows me to delete the item inline on table without having navigate away from my listing. All I need to do is confirm the delete through the javascript confirm.

My action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        db.Users.Remove(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I'm now trying the same thing but with a linkage to my web service which will process the delete on the database.

The only difference is in the controller which now looks like this:

```
private async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    string url = String.Format("api/user/{0}", id);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49474/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(url);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Just to be thorough, here's the web service code to delete the record:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var existing = db.Users.Find(id);

        if (existing != null)
        {
            db.Users.Remove(existing);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Object ID not found");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ReportError(ex, "DELETE USER");
    }
}
```

This gives me the javascript confirm but the delete doesn't happen on the database and I get an error screen that says no view exists.

Upon debugging, I find that the functions above aren't even requested. I feel like I need to add something into the controller, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: private async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id) ... your controller's action should be public.

Comment: How are you not navigating away from the page when doing this:         `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: Another point, if you are using JS, return RedirectToAction("Index"); won't work.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio if that's the problem I'm going to ram my head against that wall over there ->          |

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I've just ran into a wall like I said I would because it seems the problem was the fact that I'd declared the delete function as private... Thanks, please make an answer and you'll get fake internet points for it

Comment: @JamieRees apparently because the function wasn't declared public so nothing in it actually executed

Comment: Yep. Makes sense. I would recommend you use Json responses and preform an Ajax call and then return a JSON object with the result/fail to do this sort of work, or use SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your controller's action to public:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    string url = String.Format("api/user/{0}", id);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49474/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(url);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```